# AS3 Extra Work When Getting/Setting a Property

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, setter, getter

I don't know if this has a special name or even possible. Consider this code;

```
public dynamic class Foo {
    public function set (_key:String,_value:*):void {
        this[_key] = _value;
        trace(this[_key] + " property added.");
    }
}
```

The trace represents some extra work to be done with the property key and/or value. Now we can create any property using the set function.

```
myFoo.set("prop1",14);
myFoo.set("prop2","test");
etc...
```

Is there a way to modify this function, so that it will take effect for any property?

```
myFoo.prop1=14;
myFoo.prop2="test";
```

I want it to act like a global setter function which takes effect when you create/modify any property of the object. I intend to create a get function in a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extend the [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) class and override `setProperty`

```
override flash_proxy function setProperty(_key:*, _value:*):void {
    this[_key] = _value;
    trace(this[_key] + " property added.");
}
```